# events in multiMonthYear not showing when starting on same day, bug?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

Im using fullcalendar.io to show a multimonthyear calendar, but I found what i think is a bug. When rendering events some are not showing. In my case I had three events that started on the same day, two of them last 4 days, while the last one only one day, and i don´t know why event 1 isnt showing. Is this a bug or am i doing something wrong

Calendar view:

[image: calendar view]

[image: more view]

Here is the codepen where i replicated the error:

https://codepen.io/miguelTTP/pen/BabpQrp

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    firstDay: '1',
    initialView: 'multiMonthYear',
    multiMonthMaxColumns: 2,
    contentHeight:"auto",
    editable: false,
    events: [
      {
        title: 'event 1',
        start: '2024-01-15',
        end: '2024-01-20'
      },
      {
        title: 'event 2',
        start: '2024-01-15',
        end: '2024-01-20'
      },
      {
        title: 'event 3',
        start: '2024-01-15'
      }
    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

I tried just putting the essentials for it to work, tried, on event 3, putting end date. Also tried couple more things but they didnt work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) HERE

Comment: [reporting bugs](https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs)

Comment: This does look like it's probably a bug within fullCalendar. You need to report it to fullCalendar using the link provided above. At stackoverflow we can't help you with that. Thanks.

Comment: made some investigation and found that, yes its very probably a bug, i have created a issue in their github repo. Thanks for helping
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/7573